# What is the CRF range for VP9 conversion using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

## My Problem

I am converting a .mov (h264) file to VP9 / WebM using ffmpeg, and I don't know what the CRF numbers mean.

## What Have I Tried

I have read [this ffmpeg manual](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9) about 2-pass conversion, which states that:

> To trigger this mode, you must use a combination of -crf and -b:v

In [Google's VP9 documentation](https://developers.google.com/media/vp9/bitrate-modes/), I see that:

> -crf     Sets maximum quality level. Valid values are 0-63. Lower numbers are higher quality
>
> Note: Other codecs in FFmpeg accept the -crf parameter but may interpret the value differently. If you are using -crf with other codecs you will likely need different values for VP9

However, on the [ffmpeg documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264), I only found reference to CRF for .h264, not for the target VP9:

> The range of the CRF scale is 0–51, where 0 is lossless, 23 is the default, and 51 is worst quality possible

So, there seems to be a conflict between the VP9 CRF range on Google's site and the ffmpeg CRF range on the ffmpeg site.

## My Question

**What is the scale for CRF values using ffmpeg to encode in vp9 / WebM format?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libvpx is a software encoder developed by Google, and used in ffmpeg, to encode VP9. And as the Google docs say, 0-63 is the applicable range for encoding VP9 with libvpx.

Comment: Tested and confirmed on Linux version of ffmpeg it allows up to 63.